# Array of TextCtrls in Python

Tags: python, wxwidgets

I am developing a screen that has a lot of TextCtrls that can be classed together (e.g. RedChoice(1), RedChoice(2), ... , BlueChoice(1), BlueChoice(2), ... , etc).

They would be easier to assign values to and get values from if they could be accessed as a list (or lists). I've looked at `wxGrid` and it just doesn't look right for my purpose.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: A solution to what? It's really not clear what the problem is in the first place.

Comment: sorry. Can I create an array of textctrls, and if yes, how?

Comment: You can, just as you can create an array of any other objects, again, what is the problem?

Comment: Thank you. Tried it and it works. Lack of confidence prevented my attempting it. As I said: noob :)